# how to silently unmap mapped network drives

Tags: php, exec, net-use, subst

I have a local running PHP script in which I do this

```
exec('subst T: C:\\Development');
```

but in case T: is already mapped or subst' to some other location I want to unmap it first. so I do this

```
exec('net use T: /DELETE /y');
exec('subst T: /D');
```

but when T: is not mapped the exec net use will print an error to the console, and when it *is* mapped but not subst' the exec subst will print an error to the console. I want to have clean output in the console window, so no error when I try to unmap a drive that isn't mapped. the problem is I have absolutely no clue how to go about this.. can I suppress printing of the error message? if not, how do I run the commands only if the drive is mapped? then, coincidentally, how do I know if I should do net use /d or subst /d?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `> NUL` after each command to pipe their output into...nowhere.
i.e. `exec('net use T: /DELETE /y > NUL');`

Comment: I think it should be `exec('net use T: /DELETE /y 2> NUL');` since we want to redirect STDERR to null.